# In DataFrame, how do you concatenate two columns with separator only if both values exist?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

For example, say I have the following DataFrame

```
col1 col2
a    b
NaN  b
a    NaN
```

If I simply do

```
df['col1'].fillna('')+'-'+df['col2'].fillna('')
```

I'll get

```
a-b
-b
a-
```

What I want instead is

```
a-b
b
a
```

I only want to include the separator if there are values on both sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `str.strip`

```
(df['col1'].fillna('')+'-'+df['col2'].fillna('')).str.strip('-')
Out[367]: 
0    a-b
1      b
2      a
dtype: object
```

---

`stack` with `agg`

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg('-'.join)
Out[371]: 
0    a-b
1      b
2      a
dtype: object
```

Comment: what if one of my col2 values ends in a '-'? This approach might strip that character

Comment: thanks! That worked. Now I need to study up on what that is actually doing. lol